# Expression: vector subscript out of range C++?

Tags: c++

I am trying to access a variable, and print it out. However, I encounter the `Vector subscript out of range` error.

I am doing

```
cout << myStruct->myVector[0].GetCoordinate(0) << endl;
```

where
`myStruct` points to a structure that contains a vector `myVector` of points. So I am trying to print out its first coordinate.

---

**To debug:**

```
cout << typeid(myStruct->myVector[0].GetCoordinate(0)).name() << endl;
```

gives me

```
float
```

and

```
cout << sizeof(myStruct->myVector[0].GetCoordinate(0)) << endl;
```

gives me

```
4
```

---

However, when I directly print its value

```
cout << myStruct->myVector[0].GetCoordinate(0) << endl;
```

**Error message:**

[image]

Comment: Have you checked `myStruct->myVector.size()`?

Comment: The thing to know about `typeid` and `sizeof` in C++, is that they are *compile time* operators. That is, they perform their "magic" when the source is compiled and not when the program is running. That is why they work, even when normal access does not.

Comment: There are two things I would like to know. The first is what the size of `myStruct->vector` is. The other thing is what `GetCoordinate` does.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg `typeid` acts at runtime through RTTI table if present. Still, the table is statically compiled based on the variables declaration, so more or less you are right...

Comment: note, btw, `sizeof` is reporting 4; the sizeof the *return type* of the function provided (which ironically doesn't even have to be *implemented* for that operator to work; only declared). I.e. the size of a `float`.

Comment: You know that the values you are getting are inferred from variables declarations, right? There is no actual check on the value that is returned, simply there is a table saying "`GetCoordinate` will return a `float`".

Comment: @Zeta  it is 0. so this is the probelm?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg   `const float GetCoordinate(int nth) const { return m_coordinate[nth]; }`

Comment: That there is nothing in your vector? First you need to put an element inside, then you can access it :)

Comment: @mavErick Wel.. if your vector has size 0, its empty.. you can not access its elements, where there are none

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your vector is empty. Any index that's not between `0` and `.size()` (excluding the latter) is out of range. Since there is no index between `0` and `0`, every index is out of range.

You need to populate your vector first, e.g. use `.resize` or `.push_back`.

Answer (score 1):

Issue caused by:

`tlen = __byte_encode_array(buf, offset + pos, maxlen - pos, &this->data[0], this->size);`

Impossible to access a non-existing element in a vector.